# Get a variable number of columns in an EF Select statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums

Given the following code:

```
public Charts(chartType chartStyle, DateTime[] dateRange, dataColumn[] column){
        //get the data and store it
        switch (chartStyle) {
            case chartType.Bar:
                //requires a span for x, min and max for y
                ChartData = db.visitorInformation
                    .Where(w => w.dateOfVisit >= dateRange[0])
                    .Where(w => w.dateOfVisit <= dateRange[1])
                    .Select(c => new visitorInformation {
                        dateOfVisit = c.dateOfVisit,
                        browser = c.browser
                    }).ToDictionary(c=>c.dateOfVisit.ToString(),c=>c.browser);
                break;
           ...
        }
    }
```

The .Select can be used to specify exact columns but I need to be able to specify an unknown number of columns using the dataColumn enum array (which has types of the same name as the column names in my table and entity framework model). It seems obvious that I can't just iterate through the array to chain on the select although that would be nice. How can I go about such a crazy and silly idea?

Note that the ToDictionary does not yet take into account multiple columns - it is just placeholder code however, how would I specify a dynamic column from the dataColumn Enum array instead of specifying one in code?

Comment: Do you have a small enough data set that it's realistic to just pull back all columns and filter out what you don't need on the application's side?

Comment: Make a higher order function and pass in a Select func with the columns you need

Comment: @Servy: I *could* but I need this to be as generic as possible for any database thrown at it. It's not impossible to do this, however and may be the more realistic solution but for this project, I'm looking at a theoretical high end of 200 columns.

Comment: @reggaeguitar: I had thought of that but the question that remains is "How can I do that in an entity framework chain?" I'd prefer to do a chain just to get away from more "sql-like" code. It's beginning to look like to me that it's generally not possible. But hopefully I'm wrong.

Comment: Entity Framework is not meant for this sort of dynamism. It's an ORM, and as such, is designed to return data in standard ways. If you need something more custom, then that's what SQL is for, and it's still available to you, if you want to issue manual SQL statements.

Comment: Yeah but we hates filthy SQL statementses. I was just hoping...

Comment: Couldn't you do this using an expression tree to generate the column list dynamically?

Comment: @ChrisPratt - That's a bit of an extreme view... I'd prefer to say that EF focuses on static query generation.  It's quite possible to create dynamic queries in EF, it's just not part of the "happy path" that they show in all the demos and what the tooling makes it easy to do.

Comment: @MetalPhoenix: There's nothing wrong with using SQL. The problem comes when the statements are littered around your code. As long has you properly abstract and encapsulate the SQL in a service method or something, there's very little difference between that and using EF.

Comment: @reggaeguitar: Expression trees might be what I'm looking for. Hadn't heard of them before and I'm researching them now. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisPratt: My philosophy on Entity Framework is that it's there to prevent me from having to create all that SQLy stuff and that it should be used to perform all SQL type operations unless performance or complexity demands otherwise. If I can't specify any number of <something> using a variable (the bread and butter of programming), then EF is failing.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - While there's "nothing wrong with SQL", by going outside of EF you have to be careful, because if you mix the two, EF doesn't know what you did.  The changes you made won't be in EF's cache, and there might be old data in that cache.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: That's a valid point worth mentioning. The OP's particular use case is a SELECT, so there's no real issues there, but if my comment was applied more broadly, I could see cause for such a concern.